How to properly create global mocks with Jest?
I have a library that needs to be mocked globally across all tests. The global mock is set up using a global-setup.ts file:
jest.mock('My library', () => {
  return {
    method1: jest.fn().mockImplementation((key) => {
      ... process
    }),
  };
});

and the configuration file contains:
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./global-setup.ts']

This works, but issuing a resetAllMocks "replaces the mock implementation with an empty function", so the mock will be lost.
I have four possible workarounds, but I'm wondering if there's a better way:

Every time you have to resetAllMocks, rewrite the implementation. This is against everything I know.

Instead of resetting all mocks, specifically reset the mocks in the corresponding test file, but that can become verbose really fast.

Instead of resetting all mocks, clear all mocks. This approach will work, but then you will lose the opportunity to reset mocks (unless you do that specifically one by one).

Put the global mock in a beforeEach block. You will keep the flexibility and stick on the DRY principles, but might introduce some overhead in running the tests (I can live with that for now).
const mock = jest.spyOn(myLibrary, 'method1');
beforeEach(() => {
  mock.mockImplementation((key) => {
    ...process
  })
})



What would you recommend here? Is there a better way to handle global mocks with jest.resetAllMocks()? Or is the beforeEach() solution the most practical?

Just don't use jest.fn().mockImplementation()? Do return { method1: (key) => { /* mock process implementation */ }, }; for the module. If you need to spy on method1, do that separately, so that resetAllMocks will only reset the spy to your original (mock) implementation.
